# Avoid being flooded by Azure Devops notifications

Tags: azure-devops

We have global notifications setup to send notification to work items assignees. But since there are many fields in these work items, users complain about receiving too many notifications.

We want to setup work item change notifications to be sent only when certain fields are updated, For eg. only on state and title change of a work item.

Is this possible in Azure Devops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is achievable in Azure devops. You only need to configure the filter criteria for the notification. See below example:

Navigate to the **Organization Settings** page-->**Global notifications**-->Statics tab-->Select the **notification** your team subscribed.

[image]

Then Edit the notification your team subscribed. Add the new clause in the `filter criteria` section to only send notification on the specific fields changes.

[image]

Check out document [Manage notifications for a team, group, or organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-global-organization-notifications?view=azure-devops) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reference as well!

Comment: Lu, I am unable to add notifications for Tags while the one added for Comments Changes doesn't trigger notifications for comments add or update.

Comment: To be specific, there is a rule for when a specific tag is added but not for when any tag is added.

Comment: @Ashutosh You are right, there is not an option for tag changes operation. As workaround. You can set the tag filter `operation` to `Does not contain value`. And set a very special string as its value which the tags will definitely not contain. eg.`$?$`.

Comment: This doesn't work as after adding the rule Tags does not contain $#$, emails trigger on change of any field which invalidates the purpose of adding the rules in the first place.

Comment: Another workaround is to add a filter as suggested with @LeviLu-MSFT. I used it to filter by the title (Field "Title" "Does not contain" "a link was added")